# Is there a way to compile an executable binary for iOS using flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am developing an application using flutter. In Android is easy to distribute an .apk file for internal testing, however I do not know if there are any ways to do a similar thing with iOS.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to publish the app to test flight on App Store. (I guess this is the only way) And add testers' e-mails, so that they will have access to test it. [Here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios) you can find all the detailed instructions.